# Cant perform an SQL update when using php varibles

Tags: php, mysql

I just noticed that i can not perform SQL updates when i am using PHP varibles from the link
My code (I don't noticed any errors, and no error output)

```
<?php

if ($_POST && isset($_POST['hdduid'], $_POST['status'])) {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'L24wmc1nJBVP90q9yY';
    $dbname = 'watt';

    try {
        // Try to connect
        $dbh = new PDO(
            'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname,
            $dbuser,
            $dbpass
        );

        // Data
        $hdduid = $_POST['hdduid'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];

        // query
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET paid=':status' WHERE hdduid=':hdduid'";
        $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(
            ':message' => $message,
            ':email' => $email
        ));

        // Null connection
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) { // if exception
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

?>
```

I edited the code, it still wont working

Comment: Inside the condition where you check `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {`, what is `echo $conn->affected_rows;`? Also, you should be using a prepared statement.

Comment: You're also mixing APIs here. `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't work with `mysqli`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: @Johannes It checks for errors if the query fails, `echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;` (although you shouldn't display those out to the end user...).

Comment: Shouldn't be - $hhduid = $_GET["hdduid"]  and $status = $_GET["status"]

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting on, and you are checking error logs? `mysql_real_escape_string` with PHP 7+ will cause fatal error because the function is undefined.

Comment: You do realize that your `if` statement is not closed. You are missing last `}`

Comment: What are the contents of `$message` and `$email`? Where do you declare these variables?

Comment: I hope you didn't post your real password on here

Comment: Placeholders should not be quoted. If they are they become a string, not a placeholder, and won't be bound.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
     `mysqli_real_escape_string`
Not
    `mysql_real_escape_string`
You can not mix mysql with MySQLi

Comment: You also can't mix `pdo` with `mysqli`.

Comment: Original code posted by op was MySQLi and has edited the code to use pdo

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution. It uses `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. I also changed the name of `$status` to `$paid` for better readability. Good luck!

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; //$password = "L24wmc1nJBVP90q9yY";
$dbname = "test";   //$dbname = "ft";

// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

$hdduid = $_GET["hdduid"];
$paid = $_GET["status"];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET paid='$paid' WHERE hdduid='$hdduid'";

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
}

$connection->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution using prepared statements.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "L24wmc1nJBVP90q9yY";
$dbname = "ft";

// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

$paid = $_GET["status"];
$hdduid = $_GET["hdduid"];

//Prepared statements
$statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET paid = ? WHERE hdduid = ?");
$statement->bind_param("ss", $paid, $hdduid);

if(!$statement->execute()) {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $statement->error;
} else {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
}

$statement->close();
$connection->close();
```

Comment: What exactly is this helping with? What have you changed other than made it worse by switching to MySQLi from PDO?

Comment: Well it worked on my computer, thats why I posted it. And I posted another answer because I thought prepared statements might have been what he was looking for. I chose MySQLi because I'm not familiar with PDO.

Comment: I am glad you are trying to help, YuKo, but you can't give an answer which is not explaining the problem or how your solution would help. If you are not familiar with PDO I would strongly recommend to learn it, because it is easier for beginners.

Comment: If you use prepared statements then why would you still need `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: I thought I'd do that to get rid of special characters. EDIT: Well I was wrong in my understanding about special characters. You are right, it's unnecessary.

Comment: ....What special characters? Why do you want to get rid of some characters and leave the others? Who gave you the idea that this function removes any characters?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What do you think the error might be?